# Get list of items changed/added/removed in Perforce . . . using BAT commands

Tags: batch-file, perforce

I am working on a BAT file that gets the list of files that have been modified/added in my local repository and then copies them to a new folder (sort of a back-up BAT).

Is it possible to retrieve that list of files from somewhere? Can I use some commands in the BAT to call perforce commands that return that list? What would that command be?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you want to backup a folder tree?  `robocopy` has a `mirror` backup option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a backup of the files you've modified or added, consider this approach:

```
p4 reconcile

p4 shelve
```

Reconcile will figure out which files you've modified or added; shelve will store them in the Perforce server (not as a submitted changelist, but as a shelved changelist).

Periodically, you can delete your old "backups" by doing:

```
p4 shelve -d
p4 change -d
```

to remove the files from the shelved changelist, and then to delete the changelist itself.

Comment: One potentially tricky part is that you'd need to enumerate all open changesets in the client, and you might run into problems if one of the changesets is already shelved.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your files in C:\p4 -- you could do "p4 reconcile -n C:\p4..." to tell you what it *would* do if you needed to reconcile changes you made outside of Perforce's knowledge.

Or "p4 reconcile C:\p4..." to open any of the files for add, delete or edit and populate your pending changelist.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. What would "p4 reconcile C:\p4..." or the -n variant do if called from a bat file? I only need the full path and name of the modified files, not anything else. Also, how would I call that command? Would I just call the perforce executable and add the "p4 reconcile C:\p4..." as an argument to it?

Comment: If called from a bat file, "p4 reconcile <blahblah>" would return a list of what it would do., e.g., "//depot/foo/bar/mynewfile.txt#1 open for add".  I like Brian's response, though, because - in the end - I think it gets you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do:

```
p4 reconcile
p4 diff > backup.patch
```

And now you've backed up all changes in the client.  Note that this won't work for binary files.